# Android - How to limit a imageview size by width and keep the scale

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my problem: I am working on a RelativeLayout view, which contains a imageview:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_card_bg">

    ...

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" <-- ?
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" <-- ?
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/test_img"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the image view can fill width of the RelativeLayout and keep the ratio, but my code above doesn't work. I was wondering how should I change the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `RelativeLayout`'s width to `fill-parent`.